# Using a static class, or a declared one

Tags: c#, class, static, definition

I'm currently trying to read some binary data using the BinaryReader. I've created a helper class to parse this data. Currently it is a static class with this kind of methods:

```
public static class Parser
{
     public static ParseObject1 ReadObject1(BinaryReader reader){...}
     public static ParseObject2 ReadObject2(BinaryReader reader{...}
}
```

Then I use it like this:

```
...
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(@"file.ext");
ParseObject1 po1 = Parser.ReadObject1(br);
...
ParseObject1 po2 = Parser.ReadObject2(br);
...
```

But then I started thinking, I could also just initialize the class like this

```
Parser p = new Parser(br);
ParseObject1 po1 = Parser.ReadObject1();
```

What would be a better implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Which is faster isn't really relevant here; your concerns are more about concurrency and architecture.

In the case of a static Parser class to which you pass the BinaryReader as an argument to the ReadObject call, you're providing all of the data to the method, and (presumably, from your example) not persisting any data about the Reader in the Parser; this allows for you to instantiate multiple BinaryReader objects and to invoke the Parser on them separately, with no concurrency or collision problems.  (Note that this ONLY applies if you have no persistent static data within your Parser object.)

On the other hand, if your Parser gets passed the BinaryReader object to operate upon, it's presumably persisting that BinaryReader data within itself; there's a potential complication there if you have interleaved calls to your Parser with different BinaryReader objects.

If your Parser doesn't need to maintain state between ReadObject1 and ReadObject2, I'd recommend keeping it static, and passing in the BinaryReader object reference; keeping it static in that instance is a good "descriptor" of the fact that there's no data persisted between those invocations.  On the other hand, if there's data persisted about the BinaryReader within the Parser, I'd make it non-static, and pass the data in (like in your second example).  Making it non-static but with class-persisted data makes it far less likely to cause problems with concurrency.

Comment: Great answer, I rarely run into coders who think in this fashion.

Comment: Okay, really awesome answer indeed. This makes it clear for me. Never thought of it this way. Faster is indeed not always the definition of the best implementation.

Comment: Glad to help!  I've found this way of analyzing the problem to be very useful, and I've avoided some nasty concurrency problems this way!

Comment: For now, the Parser class will never have concurrency problems. But there might be a time in my use case, where I'd like to read 2 different binary files. I'll keep them static just to avoid problems then. And I really like the readability of it.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably negligible difference in performance between the two implementations. I expect reading the binary file would take > 99% of the execution time.

If you're really concerned with performance, you could wrap both implementations in separate loops and time them.

Answer (score 1):

The performance difference between these two approaches should be negligible.  Personally, I would suggest using a non-static approach due to the flexibility that it provides.  If you find it helpful to have much of the parsing logic consolidated in one place, you could use a combination approach (demonstrated in my example below).

Regarding performance, If you were repeatedly creating many new instances of your Parser class over a short period of time, you might notice a small performance impact, but then you would likely be able to refactor the code to avoid repeatedly creating instances of the Parser class.  Also, while calling an instance method (especially a virtual method) is technically not as fast as calling a static method, again the performance difference should be very negligible.

McWafflestix brings up a good point about state.  However, given that your current implementation uses static methods, I assume that your Parser class does not need to maintain state between calls to the Read methods, and therefore you should be able to reuse the same Parser instance in order to parse multiple objects from a `BinaryReader` stream.

Below is an example that illustrates the approach that I would probably take for this problem.  Here are some features of this example:

- Using polymorphism to abstract details about where the parsing logic resides for a given type of object.
- Using a repository to store Parser instances so that they can be reused.
- Using reflection to identify the parsing logic for a given class or struct.

Notice that I've kept the parsing logic in static methods within the `ParseHelper` class, and the `Read` instance methods on the `MyObjectAParser` and `MyObjectBParser` classes utilize those static methods on the `ParseHelper` class.  This is just a design decision that you can make depending on what makes the most sense to you regarding how to organize your parsing logic.  I'm guessing it would probably make sense to move some of the type-specific parsing logic into the individual Parser classes, but keep some of the general parsing logic in a ParseHelper class.

```
// define a non-generic parser interface so that we can refer to all types of parsers
public interface IParser
{
    object Read(BinaryReader reader);
}

// define a generic parser interface so that we can specify a Read method specific to a particular type
public interface IParser<T> : IParser
{
    new T Read(BinaryReader reader);
}

public abstract class Parser<T> : IParser<T>
{
    public abstract T Read(BinaryReader reader);

    object IParser.Read(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        return this.Read(reader);
    }
}

// define a Parser attribute so that we can easily determine the correct parser for a given type
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class ParserAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type ParserType { get; private set; }

    public ParserAttribute(Type parserType)
    {
        if (!typeof(IParser).IsAssignableFrom(parserType))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("The type [{0}] does not implement the IParser interface.", parserType.Name), "parserType");

        this.ParserType = parserType;
    }

    public ParserAttribute(Type parserType, Type targetType)
    {
        // check that the type represented by parserType implements the IParser interface
        if (!typeof(IParser).IsAssignableFrom(parserType))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("The type [{0}] does not implement the IParser interface.", parserType.Name), "parserType");

        // check that the type represented by parserType implements the IParser<T> interface, where T is the type specified by targetType
        if (!typeof(IParser<>).MakeGenericType(targetType).IsAssignableFrom(parserType))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("The type [{0}] does not implement the IParser<{1}> interface.", parserType.Name, targetType.Name), "parserType");

        this.ParserType = parserType;
    }
}

// let's define a couple of example classes for parsing

// the MyObjectA class corresponds to ParseObject1 in the original question
[Parser(typeof(MyObjectAParser))] // the parser type for MyObjectA is MyObjectAParser
class MyObjectA
{
    // ...
}

// the MyObjectB class corresponds to ParseObject2 in the original question
[Parser(typeof(MyObjectAParser))] // the parser type for MyObjectB is MyObjectBParser
class MyObjectB
{
    // ...
}

// a static class that contains helper functions to handle parsing logic
static class ParseHelper
{
    public static MyObjectA ReadObjectA(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        // <code here to parse MyObjectA from BinaryReader>
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static MyObjectB ReadObjectB(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        // <code here to parse MyObjectB from BinaryReader>
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

// a parser class that parses objects of type MyObjectA from a BinaryReader
class MyObjectAParser : Parser<MyObjectA>
{
    public override MyObjectA Read(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        return ParseHelper.ReadObjectA(reader);
    }
}

// a parser class that parses objects of type MyObjectB from a BinaryReader
class MyObjectBParser : Parser<MyObjectB>
{
    public override MyObjectB Read(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        return ParseHelper.ReadObjectB(reader);
    }
}

// define a ParserRepository to encapsulate the logic for finding the correct parser for a given type
public class ParserRepository
{
    private Dictionary<Type, IParser> _Parsers = new Dictionary<Type, IParser>();

    public IParser<T> GetParser<T>()
    {
        // attempt to look up the correct parser for type T from the dictionary
        Type targetType = typeof(T);
        IParser parser;
        if (!this._Parsers.TryGetValue(targetType, out parser))
        {
            // no parser was found, so check the target type for a Parser attribute
            object[] attributes = targetType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ParserAttribute), true);
            if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
            {
                ParserAttribute parserAttribute = (ParserAttribute)attributes[0];

                // create an instance of the identified parser
                parser = (IParser<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(parserAttribute.ParserType);
                // and add it to the dictionary
                this._Parsers.Add(targetType, parser);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Unable to find a parser for the type [{0}].", targetType.Name));
            }
        }
        return (IParser<T>)parser;
    }

    // this method can be used to set up parsers without the use of the Parser attribute
    public void RegisterParser<T>(IParser<T> parser)
    {
        this._Parsers[typeof(T)] = parser;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
        ParserRepository parserRepository = new ParserRepository();

        // ...

        IParser<MyObjectA> parserForMyObjectA = parserRepository.GetParser<MyObjectA>();
        IParser<MyObjectB> parserForMyObjectB = parserRepository.GetParser<MyObjectB>();

        using (var fs = new FileStream(@"file.ext", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

            MyObjectA objA = parserForMyObjectA.Read(br);
            MyObjectB objB = parserForMyObjectB.Read(br);

            // ...
        }

        // Notice that this code does not explicitly reference the MyObjectAParser or MyObjectBParser classes.
```

Comment: Wow xD this is quite a good flexible solution. However, it seems like it has quite some overhead for my current use case. I hower, will keep this favorited, because it really learned me something and gave me an other insight in how this problems can be fixed.